# What is an appropriate sentence for this problem?

Tags: writing

There are two boxes A and B. The size of A is twice that B. I will allocate(divide) six  apples to(into) the boxes. Four apples are allocated to A and Two apples to B. What is an appropriate phrase?

"The apples are allocated to the boxes based on their size"
Or " The apples are allocated to the boxes in proportion to their size"?
Or ...

Comment: Note that the word "apples" is plural and countable, so the verb must agree. Hence: "apples *are...*".

Comment: Also, "appropriate" begins with a vowel sound, so should be proceeded by "an", not "a".

Answer (score 1):

> The number of apples kept in the boxes are as per boxes' sizes.

This said, four apples in Box A and two in Box B. That's because the Box A is double in size than that of the Box B.

Comment: No.no. This problem is only a sample. I need the sentences similar to "is allocated to ... based on... their attribute".

Comment: @Finder Yes, so it'd be "...put/allocated in/to ..... as per their ... sizes/attributes

Comment: As per means "according to"? what is your opinion about " The apples is allocated to boxes according to their size"

Comment: @Finder that's okay  as well. But *according to*, what I think, may fit better when you talk about opinion or as stated/reported. *I planned to put equal number of apples in both the boxes but then **according to** the mail, the boxes we are receiving are of different sizes.*

Comment: @MaulikV: that is one use of "according to", but Finder is also correct that it can be used here too.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff I already said that it's okay.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possible alternatives,

> We pack our apples by box size.
>   We pack our apples according to the sizes of the boxes.
>   The apples are packed by box size.
>   The number of apples packed varies by box size.
>   The number of apples packed depends on box size.
>   The number of apples packed in each box depends on box size.
>   The number of apples in each box depends on box size.

Answer (score 1):

If I may restate your question with (I hope) fully corrected grammar:

> 1) There are two boxes, A and B.
>
> 2) The size of A is twice that of B.  *-or-* A is twice the size of B.  *-or-* A is twice as big as B.
>
> 3) I have six apples to be placed into boxes.
>
> 4) **Apples are allocated to boxes based on the box sizes.**
>
> 5) Therefore, four apples go into box A and two into box B.

In statement 1, the verb must agree with the plurality of the noun, so you say "are", not "is", because you are talking about more than one box.

In statement 2, "twice larger than" is not standard phrasing.  The options listed are all valid alternatives.

In statement 4, first of all we need the noun and the verb to match plurality again, so we say "are" because we still have more than one apple.  Then, note that it is important to specify **what item's sizes** are being used as the basis of allocation.  If you say "apples are allocated into boxes based on *their* sizes", I don't know if you mean the size of the apples, or the size of the boxes.

Comment: @Hellion.I correct my question's grammar based on or according to your guidance. I mean that the apples are divided into the boxes according to the sizes of the boxes.

Comment: @Finder, I guessed that was what you meant.  :-)  Statement 4 is intended to be the answer to your question.